# convert ajax returned (json) date to javascript date (not working in IE 9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am getting the date's in the following format (see date1 and date2) from an ajax response. When I tried to convert them to normal date, I am seeing that the logic I've applied works for one date and not for the another...

```js
var date1 = '2015-08-12T15:05:41.893';
var date2 = '2015-08-12T15:09:26.18';

$('#lbl1').text(new Date(Date.parse(date1)));

$('#lbl2').text(new Date(Date.parse(date2)));//not working in IE 9
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lbl1"></label>
<br/>
<label id="lbl2"></label>//not working in IE 9
```

**Expectation:**

Both dates in 'date1 and date2' variables should be converted to normal datetime format.

Am I missing anything in my code? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML labels are all broken.

Fix them. They are containers! Containers can't be self-closing.

Simply change from `<label id="lbl2"/>//not working` to `<label id="lbl2"></label>`.

Also, HTML comments use the syntax `<!-- -->`, not `//`. That's for C and similar syntaxes.

Check here:

```js
var date1 = '2015-08-12T15:05:41.893';
var date2 = '2015-08-12T15:09:26.18';

$('#lbl1').text(new Date(Date.parse(date1)));

$('#lbl2').text(new Date(Date.parse(date2)));//not working
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lbl1"></label>
<br/>
<label id="lbl2"></label>
```

Comment: good catch. I don't know how I missed it...

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Maybe you were thinking about `<input>`s? Or you simply copied the `<br/>` and changed the tag only?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh ... Please, revert the edit and ask a new question since the issue is different. Also, it is working fine on IE9 from here